# Replace WPF Default UI Elements with Photoshop UI Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend-4, photoshop-cs5

I am new to Creating WPF GUI Applications. 
I am a Mid Level Programmer. I dont have any idea or knowledge about the Graphics Development.

I would like to know how do I use the UI Elements designed in Photoshop in my WPF Application.

Eg: I would like to replace the default textbox or the button in WPF with the button or textbox designed in Adobe Photoshop.

Last Information:
I am using Expression Blend 4.
Any Help Would Be Appreciated, Thanks

Comment: you need to do [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the same. Also have a look at [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Try [import-adobe-photoshop-file-in-expression-blend-4](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/eda428/import-adobe-photoshop-file-in-expression-blend-4/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Starting with WPF

I personally work with a combination of [**Microsoft Visual Studio**](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng) (environment) and [**Microsoft Expression Blend**](https://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/) (elements editing).

Blend is a WYSIWYG front-end for designing XAML-based interfaces for WPF and Silverlight applications, and it's good for templates, visual states, and animation.

---

#### Editing Templates

If you are working with templates, a nice tool is [**WPF Theme Editor**](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Themes/theme-editor.xml) by DevExpress. It integrates with Blend, and the tree browser and template hierarchy are very useful for locating styles.

One thing you'll always find helpful is access to the actual structural templates for the elements. I usually find myself visiting the [**DevExpress WPF Controls**](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7875) website, which has a very comprehensive list of libraries and controls.

The **[Demo Center for DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/support/demos/)** is also a great downloadable app for extracting and editing templates. I find it particularly useful with complex elements like charts (not included in Blend), where you can toggle the visibility of elements and then move the code to your dev space.

---

#### Creating Graphics

For working with graphics themselves, I found [**Microsoft Expression Design**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=36180) to be quite good for drawing and exporting vectors into png, WPF or Silverlight formats. It has a nice simple set of tools, and you can import elements from vector. Also, version 4 is free.

---

#### Testing

I just discovered this nice tool for testing live called [**Snoop**](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It's open source, and it allows you to spy/browse the visual tree of a running WPF application (without the need for a debugger), and change properties live.

For all of these you will probably need at least a basic knowledge of how to write/read WPF. I personally use all of the previous and write custom styles for custom elements.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

But I am not so much of Designer Geek.

The real situation is this:
I have got UI Elements designed in Photoshop.
I want the WPF button to look like the button designed in photoshop.

So how do i achieve that ?

Comment: Try [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/eda428/import-adobe-photoshop-file-in-expression-blend-4/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/eda428/import-adobe-photoshop-file-in-expression-blend-4/)